# Recover BNB sent to self deployed contract

Tags: bots, solidity, smartcontracts, recovery, binance-smart-chain

I was trying out creating BOT, so created and deployed a contract in BSC from meatamask. I sent some BNB to that contract to check but it didnt work. How can I get the BNB back? Help is appreciated as I am very new to this

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a custom function in the contract that allows you to withdraw the funds, they are forever locked in the contract address.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    receive() external payable {}

    function withdraw() external {
        // transfer this contract's whole BNB balance to the `0x123` address
        payable(address(0x123)).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Below is the source code
https://pastebin.com/raw/aT6WXSfu

And its deployed as well. I was just copy pasting and checking things without understanding, my bad though. Is there any way in this to recover?

Comment: @PunithG Unfortunately, there's no function allowing to transfer funds out from the contract in the linked code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Appreciate it. Will take care next time. Anyways, my BNB is in limbo now. :D

Comment: @PetrHejda Can you please check this contract whether the locked BNB can be retrieved https://bscscan.com/address/0x2e25eA4a99Cfed65d1A6804Fa7394F5b44C69524#code

Comment: @Tanuj This looks like another type of scam contract, which allows token buys to everyone but token sells only to whitelisted addresses. Check the list of transactions - for every failed `Transfer` they send a bunch of successful `Approve` transactions so that there's not so many red exclamation marks on the page.

Comment: @PetrHejda Got it but is there any way to transfer the locked bnb in the contract?

Comment: @Tanuj This specific contract is too long for a throughout check to be absolutely sure, but most likely there's not.